# creating table but return "too many value" error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am creating a table by using the following code, I don't have too many columns but still getting errors

```
Create table corrYear as
Select  a.Symbol ASymbol,b.Symbol BSymbol, corr(a.logp,b.logp) Correlation
From logprofitDEC a join logprofitDEC b
on a.Tdate=b.Tdate
where a.Symbol>b.symbol
And  a.symbol in (select asymbol,bsymbol from pairDec1st2nd)
And  b.symbol in (select asymbol,bsymbol from pairDec1st2nd)
And To_date(a.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD') between  DATE'2013-01-01' AND DATE'2013-12-31' 
And To_date(a.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD') between  DATE'2013-01-01' AND DATE'2013-12-31' 
group by a.symbol,b.Symbol;
```

The error is

```
00913.00000-"too many values"
```

I don't know why, usually this is caused by too many columns. What to do please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that it's these lines that are causing the error:

```
And  a.symbol in (select asymbol,bsymbol from pairDec1st2nd)
And  b.symbol in (select asymbol,bsymbol from pairDec1st2nd)
```

In both cases the subselect returns two columns where there should be only one like so:

```
And a.symbol in (select asymbol from pairDec1st2nd)
And b.symbol in (select bsymbol from pairDec1st2nd)
```

If I recall correct Oracle allows multiple columns in the IN predicate like this:

```
And (a.symbol, b.symbol) in (select asymbol,bsymbol from pairDec1st2nd)
```

although I'm not sure about the last one.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple columns -- or *tuples* -- in the `IN` predicate.

Comment: @DavidFaber Thanks, that's good to know. I'm not that familiar with Oracle specifics sadly.

Comment: While Oracle allows the combined syntax, functionally it's not the same as having two `in`s: the combined syntax will require that each combination of `a.symbol` and `b.symbol` exist in the same row of `pairDec1st2nd`. The original version checks for each value independent of the other.

Comment: @Allan Oh ok, that certainly changes the meaning of the query.